# How would you say "it has been"? Context: "It has been an inspiration to mountaineers."

Tags: traduction

I'm not really sure what it would be. I would rather not use, "il a été".

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The proper translation is

Ce fut une source d'inspiration pour les montagnards

Comment: So "fut" means "has been"? In that case, would this sentence be correct: "La place fut une source d'inspiration à des athlètes, des montagnards, des peintres, des écrivains et des gens qui cherchent de motivation dans ses vies."

Comment: It would be "La place fut une source d'inspiration **pour** des athlètes, des montagnards, des peintres, des écrivains et des gens qui cherchent **de la** motivation dans **leur vie**."

Comment: Ahh ok, I appreciate it.

Comment: Just another detail. If *La place* is your translation for *The place*, *L'endroit* would sound a lot better.